# X forwarding is interrupted while ssh stays connected

Tags: linux, ssh, x-server, xforwarding

From my main host[`A`] (with a screen), I `ssh` into a relay computer[`B`] (with `-X`) from where I log  into the target machine[`C`] (again with `-X`) and X forwarding seems to work well for a while. After working on the target machine[`C`] in vim for a while though, I suddenly lose the ability to utilize the X forwarding functionality and I need to log off from `C` and `B`, just to restart the ssh sessions again, then `X` works fine again. And this happens during a normal day i.e. none of the hosts goes suspends (or powers off).

When it all works as expected, `C` shows:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

and an application like `xeyes` is forwarded and renders fine on `A`'s screen.
And then suddenly it will report:

```
$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

and `/var/log/syslog` nor `journalctl` (both on `C`) suggest anything suspicious, again the ssh session stays alive and well. Anybody know what could be the issue?

Some more details about the hosts:

- `A` is a physical manjaro box (connected to LAN)
- `B` is a physical Ubuntu 21.04 machine (connected to LAN)
- `C` is a VM on `B` running Ubuntu 18.04 (connected by NAT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained by the entry for `ForwardX11Trusted` in Debian's man for [`ssh_config`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#ForwardX11Trusted), with Ubuntu behaving the same as Debian, but not Manjaro:

> `ForwardX11Trusted`
>
> If this option is set to **yes, (the Debian-specific default**),
> remote X11 clients will have full access to the original X11 display.
>
> If this option is set to **no (the upstream default)**, remote X11
> clients will be considered untrusted and prevented from stealing or
> tampering with data belonging to trusted X11 clients. Furthermore,
> **the xauth(1) token used for the session will be set to expire after 20 minutes. Remote clients will be refused access after this time.**

That would explain why you might not have encountered this issue before if you were mainly using Debian-based systems like Ubuntu.

The shortcut to enable this option is `-Y`. So you can simply replace `-X` with `-Y` in the first *ssh* command to "fix" the issue.

By the way, forwarding twice the X11 display isn't the best method, especially when using `-Y`, because the X11 display gets exposed in the intermediate system B to other users if this is a kind of multi-users bastion system. It would be better instead to forward only the port 22 of target machineC and tunnel everything else through it. Fortunately there are options made exactly for this: the [`ProxyJump`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#ProxyJump) option and its shortcut `-J`. In the end you could run on machine A just:

```
ssh -Y -J userb@computerB userc@machineC
```

Comment: beauty! Thank you, your answer will get my upvote as soon as I have 15 points! Thanks!